# Communicating with stacked Activity

Tags: android

I was wondering is there a way to communicate between two Activities in which one of them is paused(on stack)?

I've tried to achieve it with sendBroadcast and receiving data but no luck so far.
I'm registering receiver in onCreate() and unregistering it in onDestroy() so it will still work while second active Activity is working.
I've added the filters to receiver and my intent have proper flag.

Is it even possible to make it work?
Or is there any better way to achieve this communication?

=============EDIT adding code as requested==========

======**CODE**======

-**RECEIVER**

```
    private BroadcastReceiver localBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if (intent.getAction().equals(Globals.DATA_TO_ADSLIST)) {
            int value = intent.getIntExtra(Globals.AD_ORGANIZER_TO_ADSLIST_VALUE, 0);
            if (value > 0) {
                listViewAdapter.notifyDataChange();
            } 
          }
       }
```

-**BROADCAST**

```
        Intent dataToAdsList = new Intent(Globals.DATA_TO_ADSLIST);
        dataToAdsList.putExtra(Globals.AD_ORGANIZER_TO_ADSLIST_VALUE, 1);
        context.sendBroadcast(dataToDbService);
```

-**UNREGISTER**

```
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (getActivity().isTaskRoot()) {
        AQUtility.cleanCacheAsync(getActivity());
    }
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(localBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

-**REGISTER**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Globals.SEND_ADS_LIST);
    filter.addAction(Globals.DATA_TO_ADSLIST);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(localBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: It'll be better to found solution if you post your code.

Comment: You cannot communicate with an activity that is paused.  You have to bring that activity to foreground in order for it to start any sort of processing.  Two ways of solving your issue: invoke your top activity with `startActivityForResult`, then use `setResult` and `finish` - in the previous one use `onActivityResult` to do what you need.  The second one is to use a service, which doesn't get paused in the same manner.

Comment: Do I need to use finish right after I use setResult?

Comment: @AleksG thanks for help mate i somehow managed to do it with startActivityForResult. Post it as answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an activity is paused, you cannot communicate with it directly, as it is just that - paused.  If you want to invoke another activity and then pass data back to the first one, start the second activity with `startActivityForResult` - then in the "child" activity, use `setResult` before `finish`.  For your `setResult` call, you can pass an `Intent` with whatever info you want to pass back to the "parent" activity.  Finally, in the parent activity, override `onActivityResult` - this will be called automatically when the "child" activity terminates - in there you can retrieve the data from the `Intent` and act upon it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**SEND_BROADCAST**

```
  Intent i = new Intent("BROADCAST_TEST");
  i.putExtra("DATA","TEST MSG");
  sendBroadcast(i);
```

**Register for BROADCAST**

```
 registerReceiver(uiUpdated, new IntentFilter("BROADCAST_TEST"));

 private BroadcastReceiver uiUpdated= new BroadcastReceiver() 
 {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
    String mData;
    Type=intent.getExtras().getString("DATA");
    }
    };
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!